# Can we use variable in request param of get rest call in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want    param`s  key  as   variable  whose  value get  substituted.
Following  code  depicts  my   problem.

```
         js code 

        $scope.firstNameAutoSuggestUrl='getFirstName';
     $scope.paramName='fname';
     $scope.paramValue='sa';

      testParamMethod($scope.firstNameAutoSuggestUrl ,  $scope.paramName,     $scope.paramValue) 


function  testParamMethod (url ,paramName ,paramValue)
    {
       $http.get('rest/'+url+'?cd='+ (new Date()).getTime(),{params:{paramName:paramValue} } ).success(function(data)
    { }).error(function(data)
                {}
                );
}
```

Actual  Request  formed

```
   'context root'/rest/getFirstName?cd=1417684294261&paramName=sa
```

Expected  Request

```
    'context root'/rest/getFirstName?cd=1417684294261&fname=sa
```

Is there  any  way   that  **paramName**  get  substituted  to  value  which  I have set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this not sure,

```
function  testParamMethod (url ,paramName ,paramValue)
{    
   var paramsArr = [];
   paramsArr[paramName] = paramValue;

   $http.get('rest/'+url+'?cd='+ (new Date()).getTime(),{params:paramsArr}).success(function(data){ 

   }).error(function(data){

   });
}
```

Comment: Almost. `paramsArr` should be an object, try `paramsArr = {};`

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha  Simply Awesome  sir .   Used  []   it  works (not tried {}  this). Thanks  Kalhano.

Comment: great. pleasure to help you :)

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha I don't think I have ever tried an array there; aren't arrays usually parsed out differently to give array params?